# How do i undo a substring (like return a text back to its normal length)

Tags: javascript, html, substring, innertext

please can you help me out on how to undo a substring, cause i want to make the text return to its normal length when i click on a button(span) and also to make the button disappear after its been clicked using javascript this is the code i tried using

**HTML**

```
<p class="bio">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, hello how consectetur 
   adipisicing elit. Sint consectetur provident magni 
   yohoho consequuntur, voluptatibus ghdfff exercitationem 
   at quis similique. Optio, amet!
</p>
```

**Javacript**

```
let bio = document.querySelector('.bio');
const bioMore = document.querySelector('#see-more-bio');
const bioLength = bio.innerText.length;

function bioText() {
   bio.innerText = bio.innerText.substring(0, 100) + "...";
   bio.innerHTML += `<span onclick='addLength()' id='see-more-bio'>See More</span>`;
}
console.log(bioLength)

bioText();

function addLength() {
   bio.innerText = bio.innerText.substring(0, bioLength);
   bioMore.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: you need to preserve the initial value somewhere. there's no undoing it once it's gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option you could do would be to break the parts apart and put them in spans that conditionally show what needs to be shown.  Then flip the visibility when the option is clicked.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.bio')].forEach(bio => {
  if (bio.innerText.length <= 100) return;
  
  const more = `
    <span class="ellipsis">...</span>
    <span class="more">${bio.innerText.slice(100)}</span>
    <a href="#" class="show-more">Show More</a>
  `;
  
  bio.innerHTML = bio.innerText.slice(0, 100) + more;
  
  bio.querySelector('.show-more').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.parentNode.classList.add('show-more');
  });
});
```

```css
.bio:not(.show-more) .more { display: none; }
.bio.show-more .ellipsis, .bio.show-more .show-more { display: none; }
```

```html
<p class="bio">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, hello how consectetur 
   adipisicing elit. Sint consectetur provident magni 
   yohoho consequuntur, voluptatibus ghdfff exercitationem 
   at quis similique. Optio, amet!
</p>

<p class="bio">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, hello how consectetur 
   adipisicing elit. Sint consectetur provident magni 
   yohoho consequuntur, voluptatibus ghdfff exercitationem 
   at quis similique. Optio, amet!
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible because once a substring is created, the old string is deleted from the computer's memory and cannot be recovered. Instead, I'd recommend storing the original string elsewhere and putting it back afterwards:

```
const bioMore = document.querySelector('#see-more-bio');
const bioLength = bio.innerText.length;

function bioText() {
   bio.oldText = bio.innerText;
   bio.innerText = bio.innerText.substring(0, 100) + "...";
   bio.innerHTML += `<span onclick='addLength()' id='see-more-bio'>See More</span>`;
}
console.log(bioLength)

bioText();

function addLength() {
   bio.innerText = bio.oldText;
   bioMore.style.display = "none";
}
```

This should return the bio to its original text after you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems
1) You must save the initial value somewhere
2) You cannot use querySelector on a item that is not yet added to the DOM, so one approach could be:

```js
let bio = document.querySelector('.bio');
let orgText = bio.innerText;

function bioText() {
   bio.innerText = bio.innerText.substring(0, 100) + "...";
   bio.innerHTML += `<span onclick='addLength()' id='see-more-bio'>See More</span>`;
}
bioText();

function addLength() {
   bio.innerText = orgText;
}
```

```html
<p class="bio">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, hello how consectetur 
   adipisicing elit. Sint consectetur provident magni 
   yohoho consequuntur, voluptatibus ghdfff exercitationem 
   at quis similique. Optio, amet!
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that like this. This is what happens:

1. The string gets cut down
2. You append `...` to the string
3. You *override* the contents of `bio.innerText`. You can't get back the contents after this.

The solution is to store the original, unmodified text in a variable, like this:

```js
const bioOriginalText = bio.innerText;
// ...
function addLength() {
    bio.innerText = bioOriginalText;
    bioMore.style.display = "none";
}
```